# Can I write multi extended xmp in jpeg?

Tags: image, jpeg, xmp

Sorry, poor English.

I know xmp data is splited by standard xmp and extended xmp when xmp data size is larger than 65K.
Also, I read a specification 
(http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/xmp/pdfs/XMPSpecificationPart3.pdf)

Can I write multi extended data in multi  tag? And How I can write multi extended data?

Summary QA)

1. each XMP tag  have hasExtendedXMP property?
2. If extendedXMP Count is 3, How I can write app1 frame in jpeg
   (extenedXMP is same  tag)

Example)

1) First APP1 marker

```
<?xpacket begin="?" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">
 <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
 <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
                   xmlns:GDepth="http://ns.google.com/photos/1.0/depthmap/"
                   xmlns:xmpNote="http://ns.adobe.com/xmp/note/"
                   GDepth:Mime="image/jpeg"
                   **xmpNote:HasExtendedXMP="md5(1)"**/>
 </rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about=""
                   xmlns:SOF="http://stackoverflow.com"
                   xmlns:xmpNote="http://ns.adobe.com/xmp/note/"
                   **xmpNote:HasExtendedXMP="md5(2)"**/>
  <SOF:text>test</SOF:text>
 </rdf:Description>
 </<rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
<?xpacket end="w"?>
```

2) Second App1 Marker (extended offset : 0)

```
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">
 <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
 <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
                   xmlns:GDepth="http://ns.google.com/photos/1.0/depthmap/"
                   xmlns:xmpNote="http://ns.adobe.com/xmp/note/"
                   GDepth:Title="test.jpeg">
 </rdf:Description>
 </<rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
```

3) Third APP1 Marker (extended offset : 0? 1?)

```
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">
 <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
 <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
                   xmlns:SOF="http://stackoverflow.com"
                   xmlns:xmpNote="http://ns.adobe.com/xmp/note/">
  <SOF:text2>test</SOF:text2>
 </rdf:Description>
 </<rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
```

4) fourth APP1 Marker (extended offset : 1? 2?)

```
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">
 <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
 <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
                   xmlns:SOF="http://stackoverflow.com"
                   xmlns:xmpNote="http://ns.adobe.com/xmp/note/">
  <SOF:text3>test</SOF:text3>
 </rdf:Description>
 </<rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
```

Comment: That hasExtendedXMP is an indicator that this image contains extended XMP. As to how extended XMP is serialized, I have answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253281/reading-jpg-files-xmp-metadata)

Answer (score 0):

I find it that jpeg has only one 'hasExtendedXMP'. And if a jpeg have multi extended xmp data, multi extended xmp is serialized.